# Keeping original console colors in CloudFoundry loggregator logs

Tags: java, logging, logback, cloud-foundry, ansi-escape

I have a Spring MVC application deployed to Cloud Foundry using the standard Java buildpack. This application handles logging using Slf4J and Logback. The log format uses ANSI escape codes to colorize/highlight text in the log. These colors show up correctly when I run the application locally.

When deployed to Cloud Foundry, these logs are automatically drained to the Cloud Foundry Loggregator. Now I can see the application logs using the CF CLI:

```
cf logs <appname>
```

However, **all the colors and highlights are lost**. The logs show up as plain text. Is there any way to preserve the original color codes to get better output from `cf logs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not.  According to [Cloud Foundry and Logstash](http://scottfrederick.cfapps.io/blog/2014/02/20/cloud-foundry-and-logstash) Cloud Foundary formats logs in syslog format, which follows [RFC 5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424).  That apparently only deals with plain text messages (implying no ANSI escape sequences).

Further reading:

- [[nxlog-ce-users] to_syslog_ietf discards \r \n in $Message](http://search-devops.com/m/WE2JA1clUcJTHFt42) illustrates the "plain text" connotation

Comment: Any way to double-escape color codes? At this point I'm looking for feasible alternatives.

Comment: Probably not: you could translate nonprinting characters into printable form, but that would not make the messages more readable.